# Регулярное выражение для исключения всех директорий и поддиректорий

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста:
Хочу написать регулярное выражение, которое исключит сайт со всеми его директориями и поддиректориями. 
Правильно ли будет выражение следующего вида:

```
google\.com\.*
```

Comment: Где вы используете это выражение? `\.` находит только символ точки. Т.е. [`google\.com\.*` находит совпадения в `11-23-  google.com5648945`, `google.com......... ;%?.`, `**********google.com`, `выаошщуц google.com.кю`...](https://regex101.com/r/V4ctrY/1). Т.е. в принципе, `google\.com\.*` = `google\.com`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда уж

```
google\.com.*
```

Первая точка в строке экранируется, вторая - обозначает последовательность любых символов

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Разобралась.